# The fdsink element in GStreamer cannot be used to output the correct byte-stream to the pipeline

Tags: ffmpeg, command-line, gstreamer, ffplay

Because I need to output the RTSP stream pulled from the GStreamer command line to my Python program, I use the `fdsink` element to output the byte-stream from the pipeline.
The video can be displayed correctly by using the `xvimagesink` element. The command line is as follows.

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mp4 ! queue2 ! rtph264depay ! capsfilter caps="video/x-h264, width=240, height=160" ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink
```

Correct video:
[image]

Then I use `fdsink` instead of the `xvimagesink` element to output the byte stream from the pipeline and play it with ffplay. It can't display correct video. The command line is as follows.

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mp4 ! queue2 ! rtph264depay ! capsfilter caps="video/x-h264, width=240, height=160" ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! fdsink | ffplay -f rawvideo -pixel_format rgb24 -video_size 240*160 -i -
```

Wrong video:[image]

So is `fdsink` element wrong or other elements wrong? Thank you for taking the time to help me solve the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues:

- GStreamer writes text messages to `stdout`, and FFplay interprets the text as raw pixels.
  Add `--quiet` to prevent GStreamer from writing text to `stdout`.
- Default GStreamer raw video format is "planar RGB" - red plain then green plane then blue plane.
  We may convert pixel format to data ordered BGR (b,g,r,b,g,r...) by adding:
  `capsfilter caps="video/x-raw, format=BGR"`

---

The following command plays well in my machine:

`gst-launch-1.0 --quiet rtspsrc location=rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mp4 ! queue2 ! rtph264depay ! capsfilter caps="video/x-h264, width=240, height=160" ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! capsfilter caps="video/x-raw, format=BGR" ! fdsink | ffplay -f rawvideo -pixel_format rgb24 -video_size 240x160 -i -`

---

It also works without `capsfilter caps="video/x-h264, width=240, height=160"`:

`gst-launch-1.0 --quiet rtspsrc location=rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mp4 ! queue2 ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! capsfilter caps="video/x-raw, format=BGR" ! fdsink | ffplay -f rawvideo -pixel_format rgb24 -video_size 240x160 -i -`

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me solve the problem that has bothered me for a long time!!!